# webview in recyclerview not working properly

Tags: android, webview, android-recyclerview, android-webview

I have 3 type itemview in my recyclerview and the last one is contains full of webview. When i click the webview, which is a row of recyclerview, then the recyclerview is scrolling up. How can i fix this issue.

This is my layout that containts webview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/webView">
</WebView>
```

Adapter:

```
    public class HomePageAdapter extends       RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private String htmlContent;
    private ArrayList<Slider> homePageSliders;
    private ArrayList<HomePageItem> homePageItems;

    private final int VIEW_SLIDER = 0;
    private final int VIEW_HOMEPAGEITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_HOMEPAGEHTML = 2;


    private OnItemClickCallBack<HomePageItem> callBack;

    public HomePageAdapter(ArrayList<Slider> homePageSliders, ArrayList<HomePageItem> homePageItems, String htmlContent, OnItemClickCallBack<HomePageItem> callBack)
    {
        this.homePageSliders = homePageSliders;
        this.homePageItems   = homePageItems;
        this.htmlContent     = htmlContent;
        this.callBack        = callBack;

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        if(viewType == VIEW_SLIDER) {
            return new HomePageSliderHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_homepage_slider, parent, false));
        }
        else if(viewType == VIEW_HOMEPAGEITEM)
        {
            return new HomePageItemHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_homepage_item, parent, false));

        }
        else
        {
            return new HomePageHtmlContentHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_homepage_html, parent, false));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if(holder instanceof HomePageSliderHolder)
        {
            HomePageSliderHolder viewHolder = (HomePageSliderHolder) holder;
            viewHolder.setViewPagerAdapter(this.homePageSliders);
        }
        else if(holder instanceof HomePageItemHolder)
        {
            HomePageItemHolder viewHolder = (HomePageItemHolder) holder;

            int newPosition = position -1;
            final HomePageItem homePageItem = this.homePageItems.get(newPosition);

            viewHolder.setImagePath(homePageItem);
            viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    callBack.onItemClick(homePageItem);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            HomePageHtmlContentHolder viewHolder = (HomePageHtmlContentHolder) holder;
            viewHolder.setHtml(htmlContent);
            viewHolder.setWebViewClickListener();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 1 + 1 + homePageItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if(position == 0)
        {
            return VIEW_SLIDER;
        }
        else if(position < homePageItems.size())
        {
            return VIEW_HOMEPAGEITEM;
        }
        else
        {
            return VIEW_HOMEPAGEHTML;
        }

    }
}
```

Webview click listener:

```
public void setWebViewClickListener()
    {
        this.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Crashlytics.log(Log.ASSERT, "url : ", url);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i investigate the html response then i realised that there is no any host in the redirecting url(for example google://). Then i replaced it by containing the host and it works like a charm.